# How to connect to mysql database from python using connection string

Tags: python, mysql

Hi i am using `python` and database as `Mysql`, Now i want to connect to Mysql database from python and i wrote the below code

**Method_1**

```
import MySQLdb as mdb


conn = mdb.connect('ip_address', 'user_name', 'pass_word', 'database_name')
```

By using above i can connect to Mysql succesfully, but i want to know whether we can do the same by using a connection string and accessing like i mentioned below

**Method_2**

```
connectString=Server=ip_address;Database=database_name;UID=user_name;PWD=pass_word
conn = mdb.connect(connectString)
```

But i am getting an error by using above, so can anyone let me know whether we can access Mysql database only by **method_1** or is there any way to declare the access credentials to some variable and using that variable to connect as i mentioned in **method_2**

**Edited Code:**

Actually what i am trying is given below

**example_file.ini**

```
[for_primary]

connectString=host="192.168.xx.xxx",user="username_1",passwd="password_1",db="database_1"

[for_secondary]

connectString=host="192.168.xx.xxx",user="username_2",passwd="password_2",db="database_2"
```

**file.py:**

```
import ConfigParser
import MySQLdb as mdb

configFeed = ConfigParser.ConfigParser()
configFeed.read('path to file/example_file.ini')
connectString = configFeed.get('for_primary', 'connectString')
conn = mdb.connect(connectString)
print conn
```

**Result:**

```
 File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/__init__.py", line 81, in Connect
    return Connection(*args, **kwargs)
  File "/usr/lib64/python2.7/site-packages/MySQLdb/connections.py", line 187, in __init__
    super(Connection, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs2)
_mysql_exceptions.OperationalError: (2005, 'Unknown MySQL server host \'host="192.168.xx.xxx",user="username_1", passwd="password_1",db="database_1"\' (0)')
```

So i am trying in this way because i need to connect to two databases depending upon selection in `example_file.ini` file. Is there any way to do like abobe by declaring to access credentials to another variable in `.ini` file. i am expecting is here if i get connection string from `.ini` file it taking those as `string`.

Answer (score 8):

You can't, `MySQLdb.connect` only supports the former option.

You can, of course, parse the connection string into it's constituents and use that as a set of keyword parameters for the `.connect()` function:

```
connectParams = dict(entry.split('=') for entry in connectString.split(';'))
mdb.connect(**connectParams)
```

The above splitting method is rather naive however; you probably would need a more sophisticated method that would remove unsupported options, convert certain parameter values (think `use_unicode` and `True` or `False`) and allow for escaping of `;` and `=` characters where they are part of a parameter value. Refer to the [`.connect()` documentation](http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html#functions-and-attributes) for supported keyword arguments.

Comment: Thanks for your reply i had edited my code please have a look at it

Comment: @Kouripm: That format will need a bit more parsing work; see what you can come up with yourself (python is fairly easy!) and post a *new* question if you get stuck.

Comment: actually i am using scrapy for parsing urls, i have been stucked here and seeking for help to move forward, i have googled many times and finally posted here, can u please assist me

Comment: @Martijn Pieters @shivakrishna , this is a little bit of autospam, but I made a small python library to handle the parsing of the connection strings, it's called `pyconstring` and you can find it on PyPI (any criticism is welcome)

Answer (score 0):

According to the documentation, you should be able to do this:

```
db=_mysql.connect(host="localhost",user="joebob", passwd="moonpie",db="thangs")
```

http://mysql-python.sourceforge.net/MySQLdb.html

Down in the `_mysql examples` section discusses the different ways to invoke `connect()`.

Personally, I'm not aware how to do that as a single "connectionString" that you are referencing. But you should be able to use the keyword arguments with variables.

Comment: I think @Martijn has the right answer for you. Execute that `connectParams = dict(entry.split('=') for entry in connectString.split(';'))` AFTER you get it from the ConfigParser and use that to call `mdb.connect(**connectParams).

Comment: thats returning as a string actually but conn.connect('string') does n't work right

Comment: I'm not sure I understand what you're saying. `connectParams` is a dictionary and in the snippet you'd be passing the dictionary to the connect function not a string. I don't have a mysql server to test with, but I made a simple python script to verify that `func(**connectParams)` does in fact pass a dictionary to the function and not a string.