# Cannot connect to mysql and Django when using docker compose because of different socket location

Tags: mysql, django, docker, docker-compose

When run docker-compose up, django container says

`django.db.utils.OperationalError: (2002, "Can't connect to local MySQL server through socket '/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock' (2)”)`

And db container says

`Version: '5.7.29'  socket: '/var/run/mysqld/mysqld.sock'  port: 3306  MySQL Community Server (GPL)`

It seems like they cannot connect to each other because of different socket location. I want to know if I can change socket file location.

Comment: what is the django database config and what is the mysql service name in compose?

Answer (score 0):

If you run the app and the db in different containers they can't connect to each other by sockets by default. You have to use kind of db connection string with host and port or you have to share somehow the socket file between this two containers. As for me the first options is easier.

Probably [this is what you're looking for](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/12072961/how-to-connect-to-mysql-database-from-python-using-connection-string). In this case db host will be a service name from docker-compose.yml.